# AngularJS directive, ControllerAs, scope and vm property

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Using Angular I created a directive like this:

```
angular
    .module('my-module', [])
    .directive('myDirective', function () {

        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl: currentScriptPath.replace('.js', '.html'),
            scope: {
                scenarios: '='
            },
            controller: MyDirectiveController,
            controllerAs: 'vm',
            bindToController: true,
            replace: true
        }

    });
```

`MyDirectiveController`:

```
MyDirectiveController.$inject = ['$scope'];

function MyDirectiveController($scope) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.scenarios = $scope.scenarios;
}
```

My directive HTML template is this:

```
<div>{{vm.scenarios[0].name}}</div>
```

In my parent view HTML I'm using the directive this way:

```
<my-directive scenarios="vm.scenarios"></my-directive>
```

The parent controller has a property:

```
vm.scenarios = [] // could be [{ name : "test"}]
```

As the `vm.scenarios` of the parent controller gets set after an $http call it is not available when the `vm.scenarios` of the directive controller is bound to the `$scope.scenarios` and it doesn't get updated when the parents controller `vm.scenarios` gets populated eventually.

When adding this to my directives controller, it works but the solution seems wrong to me:

```
$scope.$watch('scenarios', function(newValue) {
    if (newValue !== undefined) {
            vm.scenarios = $scope.scenarios;
    }
});
```

Comment: `bind to controller` works only for version 1.3 or later... so you have to go watch way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you should define your directive controller:

```
MyDirectiveController.$inject = [];

function MyDirectiveController() {
    // nothing here
}
```

You don't need to use `$scope` because you already bind to controller instance `this`. It means that scope config

```
scope: {
    scenarios: '='
},
```

populates controller instance `this` object, not `$scope` object, and hence `$scope.scenarios` is `undefined`. With `vm.scenarios = $scope.scenarios;` in controller you just overwrite correct binding with undefined value.

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/lYg15Xpb3CsbQGIb37ya?p=preview

Comment: Thanks, your code works with Angular 1.4.x. For some reasons I need to use 1.2.28 (I've updated the initial question) and with this version your code does not work.

Comment: I double checked 1.4.1 against our test environment and noticed that we can safely migrate to.